# PDFlib inline styling in textflow

Tags: pdflib

I would really like to be able to change font style within a textflow - seems like I was able to do this years ago but my memory fails me and I cannot see this option in the documentation.

```
Just want to do something like <font fakebold=true>My Heading</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is possible within create_textflow(). When you use add_textflow() you have to do multiple add_textflow() calls with various font styles.
In PDFlib 9 you can also use save/restore as inline commands to restore the previous settings.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you're saying - I have to break up my text into separate chucks and use create_textFlow with different styles for each...to accomplish styling changes within a single paragraph for example